# Garena windows has pink edges+ LoL cannot get past through authenthication

Tags: wine

As stated above, the windows of Garena has pink edges around the buttons and replaced the profile pictures as pink. I also get a bug report as I executed Garena.

```
 Unhandled exception: privileged instruction in 32-bit code 
(0x007b5c46).
Register dump:
 CS:0023 SS:002b DS:002b ES:002b FS:0063 GS:006b
 EIP:007b5c46 ESP:0063e704 EBP:0063e7d8 EFLAGS:00010246(  R- --  I  Z- -P- )
 EAX:0063e718 EBX:00000000 ECX:00000023 EDX:00084624
 ESI:007c4624 EDI:0063e728
Stack dump:
0x0063e704:  0063e7d8 00112804 007c4624 7efff000
0x0063e714:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
0x0063e724:  00000000 46505853 000003b4 00000007
0x0063e734:  00000000 00000340 00000000 00000000
0x0063e744:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
0x0063e754:  00000000 c0000096 00000000 00000000
Backtrace:
=>0 0x007b5c46 in hardlock.sys (+0x75c46) (0x0063e7d8)
  1 0x7effb7bc in winedevice (+0xb7bb) (0x0063e828)
  2 0x7ecaaff0 IoCreateDriver+0x32f() in ntoskrnl (0x0063e898)
  3 0x7effc20d in winedevice (+0xc20c) (0x0063e918)
  4 0x7bcb5320 in ntdll (+0x7531f) (0x0063e9c8)
  5 0x7bca560c call_thread_func_wrapper+0xb() in ntdll (0x0063e9f8)
  6 0x7bca88dd call_thread_func+0xfc() in ntdll (0x0063eaf8)
  7 0x7bca55ea RtlRaiseException+0x21() in ntdll (0x0063eb18)
  8 0x7bcb086f in ntdll (+0x7086e) (0x0063f368)
  9 0xf751a295 start_thread+0xe4() in libpthread.so.0 (0x0063f428)
  10 0xf7443eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  11 0xf7443eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  12 0xf7443eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  13 0xf7443eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  14 0xf7443eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  15 0xf7443eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  16 0xf7443eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  17 0xf7443eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  18 0xf7443eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  19 0xf7443eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  20 0xf7443eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  21 0xf7443eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  22 0xf7443eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  23 0xf7443eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  24 0xf7443eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  25 0xf7443eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  26 0xf7443eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  27 0xf7443eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  28 0xf7443eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  29 0xf7443eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  30 0xf7443eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  31 0xf7443eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  32 0xf7443eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)    
  33 0xf7443eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)    
  34 0xf7443eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  35 0xf7443eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  36 0xf7443eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  37 0xf7443eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  38 0xf7443eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  39 0xf7443eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  40 0xf7443eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  41 0xf7443eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  42 0xf7443eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  43 0xf7443eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  44 0xf7443eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  45 0xf7443eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  46 0xf7443eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  47 0xf7443eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  200 0xf7443eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
0x007b5c46: movl    %cr4,%ebp
    Modules:
    Module  Address         Debug info  Name (28 modules)
    PE    740000-  7d3000   Export          hardlock.sys
    ELF 7b400000-7b7ec000   Deferred        kernel32<elf>
  \-PE  7b410000-7b7ec000   \               kernel32
    ELF 7bc00000-7bd23000   Dwarf           ntdll<elf>
  \-PE  7bc40000-7bd23000   \               ntdll
ELF 7c000000-7c004000   Deferred        <wine-loader>
ELF 7eaaa000-7eac7000   Deferred        libgcc_s.so.1
ELF 7eae7000-7eb00000   Deferred        hal<elf>
  \-PE  7eaf0000-7eb00000   \               hal
ELF 7ec07000-7ec88000   Deferred        rpcrt4<elf>
  \-PE  7ec10000-7ec88000   \               rpcrt4
ELF 7ec88000-7ecd8000   Dwarf           ntoskrnl<elf>
  \-PE  7ec90000-7ecd8000   \               ntoskrnl
ELF 7ecd8000-7ed50000   Deferred        advapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7ecf0000-7ed50000   \               advapi32
ELF 7ed50000-7ed63000   Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF 7ed63000-7ed70000   Deferred        libnss_nis.so.2
ELF 7ed70000-7ed8b000   Deferred        libnsl.so.1
ELF 7ef8b000-7efe0000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF 7efe9000-7f000000   Dwarf           winedevice<elf>
  \-PE  7eff0000-7f000000   \               winedevice
ELF f7358000-f735d000   Deferred        libdl.so.2
ELF f735d000-f7513000   Dwarf           libc.so.6
ELF f7514000-f7531000   Dwarf           libpthread.so.0
ELF f7536000-f7540000   Deferred        libnss_compat.so.2
ELF f7551000-f7720000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF f7722000-f7747000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
ELF f7749000-f774a000   Deferred        [vdso].so
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
    0000000e services.exe
    [C:\windows\system32\services.exe]
    00000045    0
    00000042    0
    0000003d    0
    00000038    0
    00000035    0
    0000002f    0
    00000020    0
    0000001d    0
    00000018    0
    00000013    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
00000011 winedevice.exe
    [C:\windows\system32\winedevice.exe]
    0000001a    0
    00000019    0
    00000017    0
    00000016    0
    00000012    0
0000001b (D) C:\windows\system32\winedevice.exe
    [C:\windows\system32\winedevice.exe]
    00000021    0 <==
    0000001f    0
    0000001e    0
    0000001c    0
00000023 hasplms.exe
[C:\windows\system32\hasplms.exe  -run]
00000052    0
00000051    0
00000050    0
0000004f    0
0000004e    0
0000004d    0
0000004c    0
00000034    0
00000031    0
00000030    0
00000024    0
00000025 winedbg.exe
[winedbg --auto 17 80]
00000026    0
0000002b explorer.exe
[C:\windows\system32\explorer.exe /desktop]
00000057    0
00000056    0
00000054    0
0000002c    0
00000032 winedevice.exe
[C:\windows\system32\winedevice.exe]
0000004b    0
00000037    0
00000036    0
00000033    0
0000003b plugplay.exe
[C:\windows\system32\plugplay.exe]
0000003f    0
0000003e    0
0000003c    0
00000040 winedevice.exe
[C:\windows\system32\winedevice.exe]
0000004a    0
00000044    0
00000043    0
00000041    0
00000048 explorer.exe
[C:\windows\system32\explorer.exe /desktop]
00000058    0
00000055    0
00000053    0
00000049    0
0000005d GarenaMessenger.exe
["C:\Program Files\Garena Plus\GarenaMessenger.exe"]
00000067    0
00000066    0
00000065    0
00000064    0
00000063    0
00000062    0
00000061    0
00000060    0
0000005f    0
0000005e   15
System information:
Wine build: wine-2.9 (Staging)
Platform: i386
Version: Windows 5.1 (0)
Host system: Linux
Host version: 4.8.0-53-generic
```

(I have skipped entries 48 0xf7443eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000) to 199 0xf7443eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000) because it is repetitive.)

I have installed the prerequisite dlls     as stated here: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=33130

EDIT:
I have also downloaded lib32nss-mdns but the result stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

Solution of garena:

Clean your wine first.

Then, install the latest wine stable version and you will be okay.

For your reference: [WineHQ - Garena Garena Plus (Beta) - Wine Application Database](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=33130)